# Test that a function calls another function with Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have a question about testing a specific situation in Mocha for Node.js. Suppose I had the following code in my app...

```
function a() {
     //...
}

function b() {
    //...
}

function c() {
    if(condition) {
         a();
    } else {
         b();
    }
}
```

If I were testing function c, how could I verify that function a or function b got called? Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution for what I was trying to do. [Sinon spies](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies) can help determine whether a certain function was called or not.

Answer (score 1):

That is what [code coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage) is for. Luckily mocha has support for that leveraging [JSCoverage](http://siliconforks.com/jscoverage/). I use a MakeFile that looks like:

```
coverage:
    rm -rf lib-cov
    jscoverage --no-highlight lib lib-cov
    @MOCHA_COV=1 mocha --reporter html-cov > coverage.html
    google-chrome coverage.html
```

1. The first line removes (previous) instrumented javascript files(folder) needed for Mocha to display code coverage.
2. Second line uses `jscoverage` to created instrumented `lib-cov` folder from original `lib` folder.
3. Third line is used to make sure that my node code knows it needs to run instrumented code.
4. Finally I view `coverage.html` in `google-chrome`.

In my mocha test file I have a line that looks like:

```
var BASE_PATH   = process.env.MOCHA_COV ? './../lib-cov/' : './../lib/';
```

That way when `MOCHA_COV=1` then the instrumented code will be used.

---

Some more interesting links about code coverage:

- http://tjholowaychuk.com/post/18175682663/mocha-test-coverage
- http://www.seejohncode.com/2012/03/13/setting-up-mocha-jscoverage/